# Unsync help needed

Tags: sync

I've unsynced and signed out of my google account on a pc at work. However, it hung onto my bookmarks and when you go into 'settings' you can access my passwords. All someone would need is the logon info for that computer.
I've tried the "Security Checkup" process and that pc doesn't show up. I rebooted that pc. WHat else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling sync does only that, it disables syncing. What was already synced stays there. You have to remove it manually.

The nuclear option is to delete the browser profile. That will get rid of everything that was saved in the browser. This includes synced data, but also history and cookies etc. so the browser will forget where you were logged in. To do that, create a new user in Chrome's settings, open its profile and delete the old one.

Comment: Going with the manual process. Might take me some time, but I don't like going "nuclear"! Thank you for the assistance! Give yourself Hero Status for at least 25 hours!!